# Error: Call to a member function connection() on null

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

resulta que estaba haciendo pruebas con phpunit dentro de Laravel 7, y en un momento con una prueba de lo más simple para crear un nuevo producto, me apareció el error:

> Tests\Unit\ProductsTest::testCreateProduct
> Error: Call to a member function connection() on null

Este es el código del test:

```
<?php

  namespace Tests\Unit;

  use App\Product;
  use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

  class ProductsTest extends TestCase
  {
    public function testCreateProduct()
    {
      Product::create([
        'name' => 'Yuca',
        'stock' => 40
      ]);
      $products = Product::getAllProducts();
      $this->assertCount(1, $products);
    }
  }
```

Si alguien conoce como solucionar el error estaré muy agradecido :).

Comment: ¿Verificaste que la conexión con tu base de datos esta bien? si el usuario, la ip o la contraseña están bien.

Comment: Sip, Cuando creo una vista para consultar y mostrar los datos lo hace bien

Comment: ¿Tienes la función setup en tu test?

Comment: Ehh... la verdad no conozco de esa función, en la pregunta está el código de mi Test, creo que no lo tengo si se debe escribir a mano

Comment: Prueba añadiendo una función publica llamada setUp(), y que en el cuerpo de la función haya una instrucción parent::setUp;

Comment: Sigue apareciendo el mismo error :(

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110099/discussion-between-lek-and-giovanni-mosquera).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crea un producto como un  atributo protegido crea una función setUp publica y dentro del cuerpo defines el atributo de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Unit;

use App\Product;
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class ProductsTest extends TestCase
{

protected $product;

function __construct(){

$this->setUp();

}
function setUp():void{

parent::setUp();
$product= Product::create([
'name'=>'yuca',
'stock'=>40
]);
}
public function testCreateProduct()
{
$product = Product::getAllProducts();
$this->assertCount(4, $product);
}
}
```